# Excel VBA userform paste text in expanded format (not just to one cell)

Tags: excel, vba, userform, paste

I'm not sure if the title is the correct phrasing for what I'm asking...anyway,

I have a userform where the user pastes in a block of data. So far I have it successfully copying the data from the form into a single cell... however I want the data to paste as if the user right-clicked and pasted it themselves so the data expanded into multiple cells.

Is there a way to do this?
Bad explination I know, see screenshots for clarification.

```
Private Sub IPButton2_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Site_IP_List").Activate
InputForm.Hide
Dim text As String
text = TextBoxIPData.text
Range("D1").Value = text
```

Form: [Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3ctu.png)

What I'm looking for: [Right Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0uN8.png),  [Intended Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKWz7.png)

What it's doing: [Form Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wVrP.png)

I have tried diffrent ways to express the data and have it input, but it all ends up stuck in one cell.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can just pass your string to this sub in place of it's current sValue, then it should work. You might need to edit a few things to make it fit your data.
That's just one of the hazards of posting images rather than text.
if those are a bunch of leading zeros, you might have to add one back in after the trim(txtstr) line. Right at the beginning: `TxtStr = " " & TxtStr`

```
Option Explicit
Sub TextToArrayToRange()
    
    Dim RG As Range         'Output range
    Dim TxtArr1             'Text Array 1 (broken into lines)
    Dim TxtArr2             'Text Array 2 (broken into words)
    Dim TxtStr As String    'Original String
    Dim LB As String        'LineBreak
    Dim Y As Long           'Iterate Y axis position
    Dim X As Long           'Iterate X axis position
    Dim lRows As Long       'Rows Count
    Dim lCols As Long       'Columns Count
    
    ' > Choose your linebreak character chr(13), chr(10)
    LB = Chr(10)
    
    ' > Choose output range
    Set RG = Sheet1.Range("B2")
    
    ' > Make txtstr = your text string
    TxtStr = "TEST-TEST-1 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 100.100.100.100" & LB & _
            "TEST-TEST-2 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 100.100.100.100" & LB & _
            "TEST-TEST-3 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 100.100.100.100" & LB & _
            "TEST-TEST-4 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 100.100.100.100" & LB & _
            "TEST-TEST-5 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 100.100.100.100" & LB & _
            "TEST-TEST-6 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 100.100.100.100" & LB & _
            "TEST-TEST-7 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 100.100.100.100"
    TxtStr = Trim(TxtStr)   'Remove dupe spaces
    
    'Debug.Print TxtStr
    TxtArr1 = Split(TxtStr, LB)
    lRows = Len(TxtStr) - Len(Replace(TxtStr, LB, ""))
    lCols = Len(TxtArr1(0)) - Len(Replace(TxtArr1(0), " ", ""))
    
    ReDim TxtArr2(0 To lRows, 0 To lCols)
    
    For Y = 0 To lRows
        'Debug.Print TxtArr1(I)
        For X = 0 To lCols
            TxtArr2(Y, X) = Split(TxtArr1(Y), " ")(X)
            Debug.Print TxtArr2(Y, X)
        Next X
    Next Y
    
    Set RG = RG.Resize(lRows + 1, lCols + 1)
    RG = TxtArr2
    RG.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
End Sub
```

Current Output:

[image]